# Hi Can we have delay timer with one Shot ON/OFF?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, inductor, timer, 555

Need a Timer circuit like, for 20 sec it should be on then completely off. generally RC timer gets off gradually so the buzzer sounds for long.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No, you can't have a delay without any capacitors. Now revise your question until it says what you're actually trying to ask.

Comment: No problem in changing question, iam concerned of solution

Comment: You could make a time delay using an inductor instead. But it wouldn't solve the problem. A microcontroller running on its internal -RC - oscillator would probably be the lowest parts count solution.

Answer (score 4):

> generally RC timer gets off gradually so the buzzer sounds for long.

Use a comparator on the RC output then you get a well-defined on/off signal to drive your buzzer: -

[image]

> Can we have delay timer without capcitor?

No, that would be silly and is not what you really want.

Comment: For me the problem is voltage may vary from 12volt to 8volt (rechargeable battery operated), the circuit should operate with that range.

Comment: Even more reason to use a comparator - it's threshold voltage will increase or decrease with the capacitor disharge curve as supply voltage rises or falls. Thus, the timing remains fairly constant.

Comment: HiAndy could you refer any comparator ic or circuit for this voltage range.  If voltage is fixed, a relay could have fixed this problem

Comment: The LM393 dual comparator should fit the bill. You can't use a relay that easily because it will need buffering from the RC to ensure the RC decay doesn't get corrupted by the load of the relay.

Comment: Hi, is it achievable like continuous buzzer sound upto 20 sec then complete off, there should not be any milli sec initial delay

Comment: There will be a few microseconds delay added by the comparator but compare this with the several milli second delay of a relay to put it into context.

Answer (score 0):

The most accurate and cheap solution would be to use something like AVR ATTiny. you can periodically use an interrupt from an internal timer to increase a register value and check every time if it has reached your desired value, then you can switch off or on a digital output which drives your load or if the load is too much for the MCU, you could use a simple transistor. the internal RC capacitor is accurate enough IMO but if you would like you can use external crystal as well.